# Gmail stripping out tags e.g. <audio>

Tags: html, gmail

I am trying to send a html 5 newsletter with an  tag in but gmail strips it out, does anyone know how to play a streaming audio mp3(ogg) file to a gmail account?

happy to consider anything other than html 5

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Gmail strips it out, you could provide a fall back of an image of a frame of the video with a play button that takes you to another page that plays the video.